# OneSignal subscriptionChange doesn't trigger

Tags: push-notification, onesignal

I'm trying to assign a tag to my users in Onesignal as soon as they accept the notification permission. The pop up shows up I click on Accept and the browser permission shows up and I click on accept on that as well. But subscriptionChange never gets triggered and no user gets added to my Onesignal. I did everything but couldn't figure it out.

```
  const OneSignal = window.OneSignal || []

  OneSignal.push(['init', {
    appId: 'xxx',
    autoRegister: false,
    notifyButton: {
      enable: false, /* Set to false to hide */
    },
    welcomeNotification: {
      'title': 'Success',
      'message': 'Thanks for subscribing!',
    },
    promptOptions: {
      /* actionMessage limited to 90 characters */
      actionMessage: 'can we?',
      /* acceptButtonText limited to 15 characters */
      acceptButtonText: 'ALLOW',
      /* cancelButtonText limited to 15 characters */
      cancelButtonText: 'NO THANKS',
    },
  }])

  OneSignal.push(['getNotificationPermission', (permission) => {
    if(permission === 'default') {
      OneSignal.push(() => {
        OneSignal.showHttpPrompt()
      })
    }
  }])

  OneSignal.push(() => {
    // Occurs when the user's subscription changes to a new value.
    OneSignal.on('subscriptionChange', (isSubscribed) => {
      if(isSubscribed) {
        if(userData) {
          const email = getEmail()
          OneSignal.sendTag('email', email)
        }
      }
    })
  })
```

Comment: Having the same issue, any luck?

Comment: @Avi nope, turned onesignal off for now.

Comment: Working on Firefox and Safari, not on Chrome. Any updates?

Comment: Ok on Chrome it seems working with Https, not Http.